# How to bundle one jar into another in android project

Tags: android, eclipse, build, jar, android-library

I'm writing a android library (no resources), and planning to distribute it as jar. My library.jar depends on third party libraries say: thirdParty_1.jar and thirdParty_2.jar. I'm building library.jar in eclipse. thirdParty_1.jar and thirdParty_2.jar are included in build path and order of export is checked for both.
When I drop library.jar in a sample app, it gives the run time exception that the classes in third-party library is not found.

Do you know whats the correct way to wrap third-party libraries into your own jar and distribute it as a standalone jar?

[Update]
I'm able to create one jar using Eclipse FatJar plugin. Is it the only way to ship dependencies along with your jar?

Comment: If you are currently trying to create an Android library, I mean, not a Java library but a real Android library with resources, then you cannot pack it into a jar. (by design)

Comment: @thibaultd: Yes, I know what you mean. I don't have any resources in my library, just plain java like code. I was able to spin a jar and was able to use it from another app before I had to add dependency of this new external jar. I'm putting external jar under "libs" folder and I see it getting included in "Android Dependencies" as well, but it fails at run time and gives NoClassDefFound for classes in external jar.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this using ant's [`zip`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) task at `-post-build`.

Edit `build.xml` at the bottom to look like so:

```
<!-- version-tag: custom -->
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
<target name="-post-build">
    <zip destfile="bin/my-library.jar">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="bin/" includes="classes.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="libs/" includes="*.jar"/>
    </zip>
</target>
```

I'm not sure how Eclipse handles the build process, since I exclusive use the command-line SDK tools for development, but it probably calls on `ant debug` or `ant release` or something, all of which depend on the `-post-build` target.